# SQL Type-casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, casting

I'm dividing some integers x & y in MS SQL, and I wan the result to be in a floating-point form.  5/2 should equal 2.5.  When I simply do

```
SELECT 5/2
```

I get 2, which doesn't suprise me, since it's creating an int from two ints.  I know I can force it to a float by doing:

```
SELECT CAST(5 AS FLOAT)/CAST(2 AS FLOAT);
```

but that seems like overkill.  I find that I can just as easily (and much more readably) get the same result by using

```
SELECT (0.0+5)/2;
```

I'm guessing that this is just some sort of implicit type-casting?  Is there some reason either method is better/worse?

Comment: If you're using literals (and not variables) then you could also use 5.0/2.0. My guess is that you do the 0.0+ because the 5 is actually a variable or column in your code, but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Or if you only want 2 decimal places, times both by 100, so your client app sees 250.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually variables.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the covers there's no difference in implementation.  The implicit casts accomplish the same thing as your explicit casts.

Answer (score 2):

Since you write 0.0, TSQL interprets this as float value. All following ints are implicitly cast to float.

See also the [implicit data type conversion matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in the section Implicit Conversions

Answer (score 2):

Not sure something being shorter is more readable since true reading involves comprehension.

```
SELECT CAST(5 AS FLOAT)/CAST(2 AS FLOAT);
```

There really is no doubt what the intention is here and will be understood when you come back to the code 6 months from now or when another developer looks at it for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, JeffO!  Note that I didn't claim it was more readable by merely "being shorter" - often when I'm looking at code which is a big mess of parenthesis/functions, I have a harder time seeing what it's doing "at a glance", as opposed to the last example I provided.  But your point is taken - if you pull it apart, it IS more explicit what it's doing.

Thanks again!